# How to route the angular url to default component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-routing

I am practicing by modifying the Tour of Heroes code.

I am in routing where if you pass nothing apart from **localhost:4200** then it redirects to dashboard component.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent} from './heroes/heroes.component'

const routes: Routes = [{path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent},
                        {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent } ,
                        {path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch:'full' },
                        ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

but something weird is happening, if i remove this line

```
 {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
```

then it stops redirecting to the dashboard component. Why? It should not effect the routing to dashboard since it is just above the path:'' code and also I am not passing /dashboard in the url. Why it's effecting the default path code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Affects it because your path is using the attribute **"redirectTo"** and that make reference to **an existing path**, in this case, **"/dashboard"** so, if that path doesn't exist (if you remove the path '/dashboard') the redirect will fail.

[image]

If you want to make a redirect without reference from another path, you could use Sander Wooming's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To define the root path, an empty path is enough. Just redirect it to the DashboardComponent.You do not have to redirect it with redirect To.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent} from './heroes/heroes.component'

const routes: Routes = [{path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent},
                        {path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
                        ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: yeah i know that but whats being the reason behind my code to act like this?